# How to add Ip Aliases with Two Gateway on same nic Centos

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have 2 allocated address range, example

1. 10.10.12.25/28
2. 10.12.12.24/28

How to add Ip Aliases with Two Gateway on same nic with Centos?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to add IP addresses in different ranges using the `ip` command or simply creating `ifcfg-eth0:xxx` files, but you can have only one default gateway. Here's an example on one of my servers:

```
[dkaarsemaker@gateway-001 network-scripts]$ cat ifcfg-eth1:179
# Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet
DEVICE=eth1:179
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=87.233.215.179
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
[dkaarsemaker@gateway-001 network-scripts]$ cat ifcfg-eth1:42
DEVICE=eth1:179
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=213.239.169.42
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
[dkaarsemaker@gateway-001 network-scripts]$ ip a l dev eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:11:5b:e0:14:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 87.233.215.178/28 brd 87.233.215.191 scope global eth1
    inet 87.233.215.179/28 brd 87.233.215.191 scope global secondary eth1:179
    inet 213.239.169.42/25 brd 213.239.169.127 scope global secondary eth1:42
    inet6 fe80::e611:5bff:fee0:145c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But still only one default gateway:

```
[dkaarsemaker@gateway-001 ~]$ route -n | grep G
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         87.233.215.177  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add default gateway here.

```
cat<<.>>/etc/sysconfig/network
GATEWAY=<default gateway ip>
.
```

For first block 10.10.12.25/28;
network = 10.10.12.16, broadcast = 10.10.12.31. Assuming ip = 10.10.12.17 for host and ip = 10.10.12.18 for gateway.

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
cat<<. >ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.10.12.17
PREFIX=28
DEFROUTE=no
GATEWAY=10.10.12.18
.
```

Add static routes;

```
cat<<.>route-eth0
ADDRESS0=<address of the network you want to reach thru this gateway>
NETMASK0=<netmask for ADDRESS0>
GATEWAY0=10.10.12.18
.
```

For the second block 10.12.12.24/28;
network = 10.12.12.16, broadcast = 10.12.12.31. Assuming ip = 10.12.12.17 for host and ip = 10.12.12.18 for gateway.

```
cat<<. >ifcfg-eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.12.12.17
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
DEFROUTE=no
GATEWAY=10.12.12.18
.
```

Add static routes;

```
cat<<.>route-eth0:1
ADDRESS0=<address of the network you want to reach thru this gateway>
NETMASK0=<netmask for ADDRESS0>
GATEWAY0=10.12.12.18
.       
service network restart
netstat -rn
```

Comment: The other answer is correct: more than one default route does not make sense.

Comment: You can have more than one 'gateway' leading to different networks. Only one 'default route | gateway' works but more than one can be added, the last added one works. @CentosNewbie didn't say 'default gateway'.